# How can I track down the origin of this exception?

Tags: android, android-widget

It's happening inside the Android framework, and so hard to understand either what's causing it, or how to fix it or workaround it. The exceptions are being logged from customer usage - I cannot reproduce the error, and customer reports are anonymous so I cannot ask them for more details.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent(PopupWindow.java:1359)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2431)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1741)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this exception? How?

Comment: you should use debugger to find what line causes exception inyour code. Then after post that piece of code and wait for advise :)

Comment: The exception is in logs from customers using the app, I am not seeing this exception myself.

Comment: you should request for steps to reproduce the exception then.

Comment: The reports are coming through analytics, I do not know who the customers are so cannot ask them

Comment: I can see the same crashlog in our analytics tool (Crittercism). Since we are pretty stable now, this is our number 1 crash reason. It happens on Android 2.2 - 2.3.6. Screenshot of our analytics: http://i.imgur.com/n1bNj.png

Comment: did you find an answer for this problem? I also get this only on < android 3.0 devices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find the source code for whatever version of Android is associated with a given trace, then check out what that line is. I can tell you that the latest code indexed by Google Code Search does not have line 1359 inside `dispatchKeyEvent()`.

Looking at the indexed `dispatchKeyEvent()`, the only way I can see a `NullPointerException` occurring directly in that method would be if the `KeyEvent` itself were `null` for some reason.

Comment: Sounds very sensible to me. Many thanks Mark, appreciate you sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Have sorted out this error? I am seeing the same in the developer console. Thank you.